# Curl fetches Plain Text Shell Script, but Browser Pulls HTML

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I was considering installing Deno, and the [installation guide](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/installation) instructs to issue this command for Mac/Linux Shell:

`curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh`

Being careful not to blindly execute a shell command, I visited [that URL](https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh) in my browser, thinking it would present raw text for me to review. To my surprise, it fetched an HTML page that shows the contents of *install.sh* along with plenty of other HTML decoration.

When I `curl` that URL, it downloads raw text of *install.sh*. When I browse to it in Chrome, I get HTML.

I turned on `-v` (verbose) and even set my `--user-agent` to the Chromium string (abbreviated below), and ran the following command, but `curl` always seems to return text, and I can't discern why.  How does the server know to return HTML vs. raw text? I'm  just trying to understand for my own edification. Anyone mind explaining?

```
curl -Lv --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 ..." https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh
```

Comment: Can you post the full set of request headers from curl?

Comment: Seems to be the `accept` header that makes the difference. I.e., when I run `curl -Lv -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml'  https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh`, it brings back HTML.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on how that header gets set on the browser request, but at least I understand now why the response is formatted the way it is.

Comment: Lots of things can set the value, but there are [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values)

Comment: Ahhh... that would make sense! Thanks, @squillman.  I think we've sorta answered this one right here in the comments. I'm not sure if I should close it, or... what.

Comment: Good deal!  You can post an answer based on what you found and accept it.  That is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

As @squillman mentions in the comments, my browser's default `accept` header is for text/html, so I'm getting HTML in the response in the browser.

`curl` doesn't set a default `accept` header like that.  And presumably any request received by this particular server that doesn't explicitly `accept` text/html gets plain text in return.

I did some experiments to demonstrate.

**Make the Browser Fetch Raw Text (Javascript)**

```
fetch("https://deno.land/x/install@v0.1.6/install.sh", {
  "headers": {
    //this "accept" header will request HTML
    "accept": "text/html",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
  }
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((data) => console.log(data));
```

If you comment out the `accept` header in that fetch, you'll get raw text.

**Make CURL Fetch HTML**

```
curl -Lv -H 'accept: text/html'  https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh
```

Removing the `accept` header from the curl command returns raw text

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want to look at the raw text, pipe it to `less` instead of `sh`. That way you see exactly what is going to be sent to the shell. Curl's default accept is `*/*`, so the web server should provide the most rich version of the file.